# Check word against very large list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

If I have a list of 10,000 words, what's an optimized way to check if a word is in that list that won't slow the app down to a crawl?

Should I load the words in from a file and check against that?

```
def check_for_word(word):
    HUGE_LIST = [...]  # 10,000 Words
    if word in HUGE_LIST:
         return True
    else:
         return False
```

Comment: Is it mandatory that you use a list to store these words? 10,000 is not that huge to store in memory, but it can be slow to process. A tree would be more appropriate. EDIT: Realized that a set was probably way better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert a list to set - strings are hashable so set can be easily created.

Look-up in set is O(1), where for list it's O(n), where n is a length of list.

```
HUGE_SET = set(HUGE_LIST)   # or frozenset, if it's constant and words won't be added to it
return word in HUGE_SET
```

Also, consider moving creation of huge list and huge set outside of function body. Right now list is recreated every time function is called.

**List timings:**

```
$ python -m timeit -s "words = list(map(str, xrange(10000)))" -n 10000 "'5000' in words"
10000 loops, best of 3: 58.2 usec per loop
```

**Frozenset timings:**

```
$ python -m timeit -s "words = frozenset(map(str, xrange(10000)))" -n 10000 "'5000' in words"
10000 loops, best of 3: 0.0504 usec per loop
```

Comment: But note that creation of set takes more time than creation of normal lists.

Answer (score 2):

- If you won't be doing any modification in the list, use [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) instead of list.
- If the items in the list are unique, it is even better to use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) then.

Lookup will be faster with tuple/set as compared to lookup in list

Answer (score 1):

Read the words in from a file and turn them into a `set` of words. Checking membership of a set is very fast (and 10,000 is not "very large" :-)).

```
with open('words.txt') as words:
    wordset = {word.strip() for word in words}

return word in wordset
```

(though it would help if you didn't have to read it in each time, keep it around in a variable -- building the set each time takes longer than checking if a word is in it in your original way)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a slightly indirect route, writing a function that, given a file containing all your words, returns a function to check membership

```
def make_checker(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        # Hp: one word per line, you can adjust the code for a different format
        # this line builds a set by a _set comprehension_
        words = {word.strip() for word in f}
    def the_checker(word):
        return word in words
    return the_checker
```

That you can use like this

```
check_4 = make_checker('corpus_of_4_letter_words.txt')
...
if check_4(answer.strip()):
    print('Please, please do not use these words.')
```